# Export data form xls form multiple form post]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, zend-framework

```
 <?php foreach($renewals as $row) { ?>
            <tr >
                <td style="width:50%;"><?php echo $row['renew_year']; ?></td>
                <td style="width:40%;"><?php echo $row['total']; ?></td>

                <td><a href="<?php $options['id'] = 18; echo $this->url("admin",$options); ?>?renew_year=<?php echo $row['renew_year']?>">View</a>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" name="exportXLSRvt" id="exportXLSRvt" class="button exportIcon" title="Export XLS">
                <form id="frmExportRvt" name="frmExport" method="post"
                      action="<?php echo $this->url("admin", array("controller" => "members", "action" => "indexExport", "id" => 18)); ?>?renew_year=<?php echo $row['renew_year'] ?>"
                      style="display: none;">
                    <input type="hidden" name="hdn_export_type" id="hdn_export_type" value="xls"/>
                </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
```

The above code is export data to xls i have created multiple form..... depends on the data but we ever i am click on the image it post the same data 
so if any body is having alternate solution then plz help me ]

Answer (score 0):

If, whatever images you click on, you get always the same data, it simply means that you have always the same action under every form.

So I will focus on this line

```
 action="<?php echo $this->url("admin", array("controller" => "members", 
 "action" => "indexExport", "id" => 18)); ?>
 ?renew_year=<?php echo $row['renew_year'] ?>"
```

Maybe you have to switch to something like this:

```
 action="<?php echo $this->url("admin", array("controller" => "members", 
 "action" => "indexExport", "id" => 18, "renew_year" => $row['renew_year'])); ?>"
```

You should be able to call $_GET['renew_year'] from your controller and load the proper data.

Comment: renew_year i am getting is some thing like this 2006, 2007,.... 
so when u click on submit button.... only first form action us passed

Comment: I noticed two things: First, you may need a "submit" button inside your form. Second, if you want to get $row['renew_year'] through $_POST instead of $_GET, just add an hidden input with $row['renew_year'] as value